# Flutter:How to handle list in model?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to handle a model which has a list but I stucking in between I am not getting any idea how to handle list which is in my model first of all I am getting data from api and I am storing Jason object in my model which is working perfect following is my json model

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "success": true,
    "messages": [],
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 35,
            "title": "Astrology",
            "filename": "Astrology.jpg",
            "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
            "directcalling": 1,
            "parentid": null,
            "subcat": []
        },
        {
            "id": 36,
            "title": "Muhurtam",
            "filename": "Muhurtam.jpg",
            "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
            "directcalling": 1,
            "parentid": null,
            "subcat": [
                {
                    "id": 50,
                    "title": "abc",
                    "filename": "abc.png",
                    "mimetype": "image/png",
                    "directcalling": 0,
                    "parentid": 36,
                    "subcat": []
                }
```

in the above json object only few of them has subcategories now in flutter I had created a dropdown list where all categories will displayed upon selecting a category it navigate to another screen where user can update selected category details.If selected category has a sub categories then it will displayed in a dropdown list where user can update details of selected category but here I face a problem.I want to give user a option to select sub category or not but here if user does not select a sub category I am facing following error
[image]if selected I am not facing above error and if user selected a category.And if user selected a category and hit on save button I am facing following error
[image] I know that I am calling data model directly without calling id from my data model basically my code should be something like

```
final catIndex = id.subcat.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
```

but here in above code how do I return id which is in data model to my update function
following is my model where I am saving all data in model

```
class Categories {
  Categories({
    required this.statusCode,
    required this.success,
    required this.messages,
    required this.data,
  });
  late final int statusCode;
  late final bool success;
  late final List<dynamic> messages;
  late final List<Data> data;

  Categories.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    statusCode = json['statusCode'];
    success = json['success'];
    messages = List.castFrom<dynamic, dynamic>(json['messages']);
    data = List.from(json['data']).map((e) => Data.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['statusCode'] = statusCode;
    _data['success'] = success;
    _data['messages'] = messages;
    _data['data'] = data.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Data {
  Data({
    this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.filename,
    required this.mimetype,
    required this.directcalling,
    this.parentid,
    this.subcat,
  });
  late final int? id;
  late final String title;
  late final String filename;
  late final String mimetype;
  late final int directcalling;
  late final Null parentid;
  late final List<Subcat>? subcat;

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    filename = json['filename'];
    mimetype = json['mimetype'];
    directcalling = json['directcalling'];
    parentid = null;
    subcat = List.from(json['subcat']).map((e) => Subcat.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    // _data['id'] = id;
    _data['title'] = title;
    _data['filename'] = filename;
    // _data['mimetype'] = mimetype;
    _data['directcalling'] = directcalling;
    // _data['parentid'] = parentid;
    // _data['subcat'] = subcat.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Subcat {
  Subcat({
    this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.filename,
    required this.mimetype,
    required this.directcalling,
    this.parentid,
    this.subcat,
  });
  late final int? id;
  late final String title;
  late final String filename;
  late final String mimetype;
  late final int directcalling;
  late final int? parentid;
  late final List<dynamic>? subcat;

  Subcat.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    filename = json['filename'];
    mimetype = json['mimetype'];
    directcalling = json['directcalling'];
    parentid = json['parentid'];
    subcat = List.castFrom<dynamic, dynamic>(json['subcat']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    //_data['id'] = id;
    _data['title'] = title;
    _data['filename'] = filename;
    //_data['mimetype'] = mimetype;
    _data['directcalling'] = directcalling;
    //_data['parentid'] = parentid;
    //_data['subcat'] = subcat;
    return _data;
  }
}
```

now I am receiving id from my data model by below code

```
Data findById(int id) {
    return categories!.data.firstWhere((cat) => cat.id == id);
  }
```

now I want to pass this id in function parameter to get id subcategories.now my question is how to pass this particular id detail as parameter in function
following is my widget tree where I am getting data model id and sub categories of that id.By using below code I am getting id details which is in my data model

```
final catId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as int;
    final loadedProduct = Provider.of<Category>(
      context,
      listen: false,
    ).findById(catId);
```

below code describes dropdown list if my id has subcategories

```
loadedProduct.subcat == null
              ? Container()
              : Consumer<Category>(
                  builder: (context, value, child) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        DropdownButton<String>(
                          elevation: 16,
                          isExpanded: true,
                          hint: Text('please select sub category'),
                          items: loadedProduct.subcat!.map((v) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                onTap: () {
                                  subcat = v.id;

                                  _initValues = {
                                    'title': v.title,
                                  };
                                },
                                value: v.title,
                                child: Text(v.title));
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            value.updatesubcat(val!);
                            print(val);
                          },
                          value: value.sub,
                        ),
```

in below code I am trying to call update function where I want to send id as parameter

```
void _saveForm() async {
    print('save form');
    final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }
    _form.currentState!.save();
    if (_editedCategory.id != null) {
      await Provider.of<Category>(context, listen: false)
          .updateCatAtributes(_editedSubCategory.id!, context, _editedCategory);
    }

  }
```

above are the 2 issues that I am facing
**1.Dropdown list error if user does not select item and click save button**
**2.passing parameter in update function**

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the default comparator of your models objects. The first error occure because the DropDownItem widget did'nt know how to compare each objects and determine the select one. So at sometimes there is none, sometimes multiple objects corresponds to the select value which is impossible.

You can use the [equatable package](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) to solve the problems or implements the comparator method [by your own](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/hash_and_equals.html).

Comment: I want to keep my items empty if user doesn't select any item from dropdown

Comment: Your text give no indication about how and when this error occure. So i assume you must add breakpoints and debiug, to find the solution.